# Expo + React Native with PayU Money payment gateway

Tags: react-native, expo, payment-gateway

implemented react native app in expo, as a last part, need to integrate PayUMoney payment gateway.

I found one library for payUMoney (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-payumoney), but this **not work for expo project**.

can some one have idea, how to integrate payment gateway, if library not available in Expo?

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. First Install the Package
2. After that run command: **npx expo prebuild** (run only once) and make change in android folder  **only if** specified in package documentation.
3. After that run command: **npx expo run:android**
4. If you make changes in android folder or install new packages run command in point 3 else run: **npm start** for faster start of the app

with this you can use any react-native package